# Использование UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, дата

Теперь код с пикерами выглядит так. Для пробы добавил атрибут в сущности как Double. Выглядит это сейчас примерно так(это куски кода не из одного файла):

```
class WorkTime: NSManagedObject {
@NSManaged var interval: NSDate? 
}
```

Сама кнопка добавление результата в CoreData.

```
@IBOutlet weak var todayDate: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var yesterdayDate: UIDatePicker!

@IBAction func wTime() {

        let todayDatePick = NSDate()
        todayDate.date = todayDatePick

        let yesterdayDatePick = NSDate()
        yesterdayDate.date = yesterdayDatePick

        let diffTime = todayDatePick.timeIntervalSinceDate(yesterdayDatePick)

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

                    let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

                    tMoney = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("WorkTime", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! WorkTime

        tMoney.interval = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: diffTime)


                    appDelegate.saveContext()

    }
```

Сама ячейка с указанием что отображать в лейблах(их всего два и отображают они одно и тоже, не хотелось их удалять):

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WorkTableViewCell
    let wt = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! WorkTime

    cell.nameLabel.text = String(wt.interval!)
    cell.moneyLabel.text = String (wt.interval!)
    return cell   
}
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку приложение вылетает. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: а что вы уже пробовали, и что не получилось?

Comment: я только добавил два UIDatePicker. Я не знаю как вытащит из него нужные данные(дата, час, минута).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо пикеру задать метод, который будет вызываться, когда меняется одно из значений на колесе

```
self.picker.addTarget(self, action: "onDatePickerValueChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

ну и объявить этот самый метод и в нем считывать значения с пикера.

```
func onDatePickerValueChanged(picker:UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    let text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(picker.date)
}
```

Comment: Все таки разобрался с Вашим кодом и этим пикером. Посмотрел его свойства. Если я правильно понимаю то выбранная пользователем дата+время это свойство var date независимо от режима пикера?

Comment: ага. по этому вам нужен NSDateFormatter. чтобы поменять что показано на пикере используйте `datePickerMode`

Comment: но каким образом получить разницу между введеным временем?  Или старый способ сработает?))ну если я код подправлю конечно.

Comment: получить миллисекунды между двумя датами используя `timeIntervalSinceDate(_:)` и перевести в часы и минуты

Comment: Исправил код. Но где ошибка, случайно не в class WorkTime: NSManagedObject ?

Comment: интервал должен быть float а не NSDate. либо вам надо хранить две NSDate - начало и конец

Comment: у меня интервал в double. Что-то с float не получилось, какая разница? Только знаков больше после точки)). Исправил ошибку с let diffTime = todayDatePick.timeIntervalSinceDate(yesterdayDatePick) . Результат был отрицательный. Теперь результат положительный, но при умножении его на 60000 получается совсем другая цифра. Например если разница между двумя датами 1 минута. получаемый результат в миллисекундах  не равен 60 000

Comment: что то видимо я напутал - NSTimeInterval измеряется в секундах а не миллисекундах

Comment: Это не меняет результата. Разница между датами указываю 1минута и получаю 0.00042998...нет смысла переводить,результат не верный.

Comment: а есть где проект посмотреть?

Comment: Не нашел куда Вам скинуть ссылку. Вот ссылка: https://yadi.sk/d/jSUB8yc0q3RBD , текстфилды не трогал в самом интерфейсе, но я их отключил.

Comment: возможно я неправильно прописал методы для пикеров. Но ошибок в коде нет(всмысле xcode не ругается).

Comment: посмотрел код. не совсем понятно что там к чему. получается, (в AddResultViewController) есть две переменные todayDatePick  и yesterdayDatePick. они обе присваиваются текущему времени и потом вычисляется разница между ними - она всегда будет доли секунды.

Comment: Спасибо что посмотрели. Как исправить? По идее дожно же работать, метод есть для считывания значений. Странно.

Comment: метод есть, но значения он не считывает

Comment: так, что то я запутался. там есть еще кусок закомментированного кода. если его выполнить, то время вроде показывает правильно.

Comment: То что я закомментировал это для иного способа нахождения разницы. Через текстфилды вписывается время. Почему я решил через пикеры все сделать, так как там сразу же дату можно выбрать и разница будет найдена правильно,учитывая что время может расчитываться с заданой датой. Через тексфилды результат уходил в минус если ввести 20:00 - 7:00. Как то так. Позже пересмотрю код еще раз, Мака нет под рукой.